# Are simulation models for components like ADCs and microcontrollers not available for Proteus?

Tags: pcb-design, adc, simulation, proteus, library

I am looking for simulation models of ADCs (ex. ADC3563, ADS52J90) that would be suitable for my application, but I cannot seem to find any. The built-in ADCs available in Proteus do not satisfy my requirements. On the internet, I can only find ECAD files and not ones that support simulation. What is a solution to this?

Comment: Why do you need to simulate an ADC?

Comment: I can't actually use one as I am working from home. If I can simulate and verify and develop a complete schematic of the system it can be easily implemented later.

Comment: I've never simulated an ADC is over 15 years of using simulators. Why do you need to simulate one?